# Find the value of minimize $a+b$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

If $a,b$ are positive integers and $$\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{3a}+\frac{1}{4a}=\frac{1}{b^2-2b}$$. Find the value of minimize $a+b$

---

From $\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{3a}+\frac{1}{4a}=\frac{1}{b^2-2b}\Leftrightarrow13b^2-26b-12a=0$

$\Leftrightarrow 12(a+b)=13b^2-14b$
$\Leftrightarrow a+b=\frac{13b^2-14b}{12}$

$\Leftrightarrow a+b=b^2-b+\frac{b^2-2b}{12}=b^2-b+\frac{b\left(b-2\right)}{12}$

We have: $b$ must even number $(1)$

For $\frac{b\left(b-2\right)}{2.2.3}\in Z\Rightarrow b⋮3$ or $b-2⋮3$ $(2)$

From $(1);(2)$ $\Rightarrow b=6k$ or $b-2=6k$ $(k\ge1)$

*)With $b=6k\Rightarrow a+b=\frac{13\left(6k\right)^2-14\cdot 6k}{12}=3k^2-7k$

We have function $f(k)=39k^2-7k$ is function covariate withg $k\ge1$

So $a+b$ have minimize when k have minimize or $k=1$ $\Rightarrow b=6;a=26$

*)With $b-2=6k$.....

this method is inconvenient with me, so i can a new method

Comment: So haven't you already found the minimum? Using $b = 6$, you get $a = 26$, and $a + b = 32$. If $b > 6$ then you will have $a > 26$, hence $a + b > 32$.

Comment: no, i need a another way

Comment: Why? You already have an answer. You showed that $b$ must have the form $6k$ or $6k + 2$, where $k$ is a positive integer. Hence $b \ge 6$. Also, you can solve for $a$ in terms of $k$ to show that $a \ge 26$. So what's left to do?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$12a/13=b(b-2)$

$\implies13|a, a=13c$(say)

$(b-2)b=12c\implies$

$(i) b(b-2)\ge12\implies b>4$

$(ii)b$ must be even $b=2d, d>2$

$d(d-1)=3c$

Now $(d,d-1)=1$